# Include a php file after it has rendered

Tags: php, caching, render

I have tried searching the forums and can't find the answer I am after, or possibly not searching for the correct keyword.

I have a page called 'page.php' and I am trying to include the url '/foo/bar.php' but only after it has "rendered".

Is it possible to completely render or cache '/foo/bar.php' before including it into 'page.php'?

Comment: Have you tried using CURL ?

Comment: got any source code to show what you have tried?

Comment: What is your goal? What do you expect would happen? What would you *want* to happen?

Comment: try with file_get_contents and pass it `URL` of file

Answer (score 0):

yes, you could buffer your php code like this:

```
ob_start();
include "/foo/bar.php";
echo ob_get_clean();
```